# Pulling data from React Form into Json with Flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, frontend, backend

I want to take input from React form and give the output in JSON format to flask API. I have dynamic data that I want to pass. However I can't figure out how to do it.

React Form

```
function App (){
  
  
  const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState([{}]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/result').then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(data => setInitialData(data))
  }, []);
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <h1 className="header">Twitter Sentiment Analysis</h1>
            <form action="http://localhost:3000/result" method = "POST">
              <div className="forms">
              <label>
                Enter Twitter Handle:
              <input type="text" name="handle" />
              </label>
              <label>
                Enter Number of Tweets (200 Limit):
              <input type="text" name="tCount"/>
              </label>
              </div>
              <div className = "button">
              <input type="submit" method="POST"/>
              </div>
            </form>
  
      </div>
    );
  
}
export default App;
```

This is the Flask function I am using

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

handle = ''
tCount = 0

@app.route('/result', methods = ['POST'])
def result():
    h = request.json[0]
    c = request.json[1]

    data = {'handle': h, 'tCount': c}

    return jsonify(data)
```

How can I neatly get the variables from the React Form into JSON format into Flask?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `request.json`, I think you can use `request.form.get(key)` or `request.form[key]`. So, I can change this block of code

```
@app.route('/result', methods = ['POST'])
def result():
    h = request.json[0]
    c = request.json[1]

    data = {'handle': h, 'tCount': c}

    return jsonify(data)
```

to

```
@app.route('/result', methods = ['POST'])
def result():
    # If you have any other keys but don't want to include
    data = {'handle': request.form['handle'], 'tCount': request.form['tCount']}

    # If you only have two keys (handle and tCount)
    data = request.form

    return jsonify(data)
```

For more handy information, you can read more at (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask)